# How to fix PyTorch RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory?

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error, gpu

I'm trying to train my Pytorch model on a remote server using a GPU. However, the training phase doesn't start, and I have the following error instead: `RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory`

I reinstalled Pytorch with Cuda 11 in case my version of Cuda is not compatible with the GPU I use (NVidia GeForce RTX 3080). It still doesn't work.

I also ran this command `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`. And it still doesn't work.

When I run the code below in my interpreter it still displays `RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory`

```python
import torch
print(torch.rand(1, device="cuda"))
```

However, it works on cpu.

```python
import torch
print(torch.rand(1, device="cpu"))
```

When I run the command `nvidia-smi` I have the following output:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure someone or something else isn't also using the GPU on your remote server?

Comment: Can you use the command `nvidia-smi` in the terminal/bash? If it works, may you add this information to the post?

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez Thanks, I just add the output to the post

Comment: It looks like some process is using the first GPU, can you try to use `print(torch.rand(1, device="cuda:1"))` instead?

Comment: @JorgeVerdeguerGómez yes it works! Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the GPU that you are trying to use is already occupied by another process. The steps for checking this are:

1. Use `nvidia-smi` in the terminal. This will check if your GPU
   drivers are installed and the load of the GPUS. If it fails, or doesn't show your gpu, check your driver installation.
2. If the GPU shows >0% GPU Memory Usage, that means that it is already being used by another process. You can close it (Don't do that in a shared environment!) or launch it in the other GPU, if you have another one free.